# Using List content for filtering datagridview C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, bindingsource, toolstripmenu

I've been struggling with this question for a few days now and I haven't found any answer yet; I created a `ToolStripMenu` array which is filled dynamically from a stored procedure:

```
ToolStripMenuItem[] itemsDepto = null;
itemsDepto = new ToolStripMenuItem[data.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i <= data.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
     itemsDepto[i] = new ToolStripMenuItem();
     itemsDepto[i].Tag = data.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
     itemsDepto[i].Text = data.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
     itemsDepto[i].CheckOnClick = true;
     itemsDepto[i].Checked = true;
     itemsDepto[i].Click += DeptoFilter_Click;
     deptoList.Add(data.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString());
}
tsmiDepartamento.DropDownItems.AddRange(itemsDepto);
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is use this `ToolStripMenu` as a filter control for the user, by default is Checked so when the user unchecks the menu, it should filter the rows with the content that is unchecked.

[image]

In the click event I add and remove values from the list depending on the state of the menu button as you can see in the following example:

```
private void DeptoFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem temp = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    temp = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    BindingSource bind = new BindingSource();
    bind.DataSource = dgvPersonalTotal.DataSource;
    if (temp.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        deptoList.Add(sender.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        deptoList.Remove(sender.ToString());
    }
    bind.Filter = "Departamento NOT IN (" + /*LIST*/"" + ")";
    dgvPersonalTotal.DataSource = bind;
    //foreach (string x in deptoList)
    //{
    //}
}
```

But the big question I have is, how can I use a list to filter the Binding Source, as you can see in the code, I can't just use the list or even try use the BindingSource.Filter in the foreach, I don't know how to resolve this problem, so any idea is well appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of deptoList?

Comment: List<string> deptoList = new List<string>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bind.Filter = "Departamento NOT IN (" + string.Join(",", deptoList.ToArray()) + ")";
```

Comment: This worked great for me man, thanks for the idea: bind.Filter = "Departamento IN (" + string.Join(", ", deptoList.Select(x => "'" + x + "'")) + ")"

Comment: I can't vote up, but I'll give you the correct answer however for anyone who wants to use this code needs to know that this is not the correct answer, it will cause your code to crash with the following exception: Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' in System.Data.dll, please use the answer posted in the comment above